# C compound conditional not working as expected (value mysteriously reassigned to other value) - possible gcc bug

Tags: c, conditional-statements

I have a program that is stuck in a loop because of a possible bug in gcc. I have tested this on multiple versions of the compiler, and it seems to stick around. A mockup version of the bug is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define db printf("t=%d\n", t)

size_t t = 9;

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    l: //label so we can repeat
    t-(t^14) //works as expected if this line is changed to t-7, but t xor 14 = 7... this line is also executed ONCE
    ==2?db,t=1: //end of first conditional, next line starts the second
    t==1?db,t=41: //buggy ONLY if t=40 or 41 on this and next line
    t==41?db,t=0: //bug in this line (after this line executes, t = 1 no matter what)
    t==0?exit(0): //terminates if not buggy
    0;
    goto l; //repeat
}
```

Please don't ask why I use this because it's for an obfuscated code contest, and I am using this particular method.

I would also like to know if this is even unexpected behavior, but I suspect it is.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't do that, for godness sake, don't... don't... just write readable code. What is the purpose of this program? it's not useful, don't learn this things, they aren't useful, trust me? a loop using a label is something that was used in the ancient programming languages.

Comment: @iharob this is for an obfuscated code contest.

Comment: Don't participate in those contests, what are they for? spend your time learning useful things. Einstien said, _Any intelligent fool can make things bigger, more complex, and more violent. It takes a touch of genius -- and a lot of courage -- to move in the opposite direction._

Comment: So the "multiple versions of the compiler" all have the same bug?

Comment: Maybe you can make it a little more readable but still preserving the bug? Are you sure you understand fully the logic of the program? As I can see in the second iteration the operation `t-(t^14)` will be performed for `t=1`, which will yield a negative result. But `t` is of type `size_t`, which is basically unsigned, so I am failing to trace it further. Is this the behaviour you mean?

Comment: @EugeneSh. 9-(9 xor 14) is equal to 2.

Comment: @WeatherVane the Cygwin compiler and the ideone compiler both have the same bug.

Comment: @101timjim The **second** iteration

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'll take a look at that then. That didn't occur to me. My take is that it will just wrap to the max value of size_t, though.

Comment: @EugeneSh. apparently 41-(41 xor 14) is equal to 2... but the contents of the line are not executed. and so is 40-(40 xor 14).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I re-wrote your expression with indenting and comments so that it can be traced.

```
t-(t^14)==2?  
     /*True */ db,t=1
     /*else */ :
     /*False*/ t==1? 
               /*True */ db,t=41
               /*else */ :
               /*False*/ t==41?
                         /*True */ db,t=0
                         /*else */ :
                         /*False*/ t==0?
                                   /*True */ exit(0)
                                   /*else */ :
                                   /*False*/ 0;
```

**Now a trace-through:**

## Pass #1

```
t = 9
t^14 = 7
t-7 == 9 - 7 == 2, therefore Condition 1 is True.
 printf 9, t = 1, goto top.
```

---

## Pass #2

```
t=1
t^14 = 15
t-15 = -14 != 2, therefore condition 1 is False.
Condition 2: t==1? TRUE,
  printf 1, t = 41, goto top.
```

---

## Pass #3

```
t = 41
t^14 = 39
41-39 = 2, therefore Condition 1 is true.
Printf 41, t = 1, goto top.
```

Because t is now back to value 1, we're back in the same scenario as Pass #2.
The cycle continually flips between **Pass #2** and **Pass #3**. (t=1 and t=41).

***An infinite loop is the proper outcome.***

(*You need to be a million times smarter before you honestly believe you found a compiler bug.*)

Answer (score 1):

The value of `t` printed alternates between 1 and 41, so when your program is unravelled it becomes quite obvious why `exit(0)` is never executed.

In the first iteration `t==9` and `t-(t^14)==2` so `t` becomes 1.

In the second iteration `t==1` and `t-(t^14)!=2` so `t` becomes 41.

In the third iteration `t==41` and `t-(t^14)==2` so `t` becomes 1.

Now repeat as second iteration.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t t = 9;

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    l: //label so we can repeat

    if (t-(t^14) == 2) {
        printf("t=%d\n", t);
        t=1;
    }
    else if (t==1) {
        printf("t=%d\n", t);
        t=41;
    }
    else if (t==41) {
        printf("t=%d\n", t);
        t=0;
    }
    else if (t==0)
        exit(0);
    else
        0;

    goto l;
}
```

Comment: apparently 41-(41^14) and 40-(40^14) both equal 2, so that is the real problem

Comment: You dumped a pile of obfuscated garbage on us, then you say that *Math* is the "real problem"???  hah.

Comment: @101timjim 9-9^14 is 2, so on the second iteration you get t=1, so the first condition will be false but the second will be true, so twill become 41. On the third iteration 41-(41^14)  IS 2, so t becomes 1 again, so we repeat on the same sequence. This is the real problem.